# How to mock inner block of Optional.of() using jUnit/mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

I have to write `when().thenReturn()` for inner block of `Optional.of()` lambda functions.

see the following example.

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMap = Optional.ofNullable(stringPath)
    .map(path -> sampleService.myMethod(param1, path))
    .orElse(null);
```

I have to write the statement in JUnit somewhat similar to...

```
when(sampleService.myMethod(param1, path)).thenReturn(sampleListOfMap)
```

is there any way to handle this block from the lambda function using jUnit/Mockito?

Comment: I think the code you mentioned should work.
`when(sampleService.myMethod(param1, path)).thenReturn(sampleListOfMap )`

Comment: No, its returning empty list

Comment: You need to create the sampleListOfMap with some valid values

Comment: How is `sampleService` is injected to the object which holds `listOfMap`?

Comment: I have already created `sampleListOfMap`

Comment: The shown code looks correct; So, the problem must be somewhere in the initialisation of the variables being used. Check all involved variables in the tested method and in the unit test. Check values and order in which things are done.

Comment: Giving an example of the full method you like to test would be helpful.